# Call Java method from JNI after callback is received

Tags: java, android, callback, java-native-interface, ansi-c

I'm building a JNI app.

From my JNI code I want to call a java funcion that updated the UI.

Basically when I receive a callback and try to get the reference to the environment I get an error of type:
`Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 1869 (ALooper)`

I've read that is not good to have a static reference to the env but I can have a static reference to the JavaVM

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

thanks a lot for your time

```
jclass globalClass = NULL;
static JavaVM* mVm = NULL;

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {
    mVm = vm;
    JNIEnv* env;

    if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "nativeTAG", "get env failed");
        return -1;
    }
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

static void callMyJavaFunction() {
    JNIEnv* env;
    jclass playerUtils = NULL;
    jmethodID updatePlayerStatus = NULL;
    jobject myObject = NULL;

    if ((*mVm)->GetEnv(mVm, (void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "jajaja", ">>NATIVE jni failed");

        /*ERROR A/libc(1853): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 1869 (ALooper)*/
    }

    playerUtils = (*env)->FindClass(env,
        "com/example/customviewcircles/nativeaudio/PlayerUtils");

    if (playerUtils != NULL) {
        updatePlayerStatus = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, playerUtils,
            "updatePlayerStatus", "()V");

        if (updatePlayerStatus != NULL) {
            myObject = (*env)->NewObject(env, playerUtils, updatePlayerStatus);

            (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, myObject, updatePlayerStatus);
        }
    }
 }

 void myCallBackFunction() {
     callMyJavaFunction();
 }
```

Comment: Where exactly does the segfault occur? When you call `FindClass`..?

Comment: Does the callback come on a thread that isn't attached to the VM? If so, `GetEnv` will return `JNI_EDETACHED` and `env` will be invalid. In that case you need to call `AttachCurrentThread` (and `DetachCurrentThread` after you're done using `env`).

Comment: I get the Log >>NATIVE jni failed and then the error on FindClass()

Comment: Then see my second comment.

Comment: You're right, may I ask you one more thing, I did'nt create another thread so why the callback get executed on a different thread?

Comment: Can't really say based on the code you've posted. Perhaps whatever is invoking your callback is running on a separate thread.

Answer (score 3):

After a wise mate show me the way I've got it.

In case anyone need it:

```
jclass globalClass = NULL;
static JavaVM* mVm = NULL;

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved) {

    mVm = vm;

    JNIEnv* env;
    jclass playerUtils = NULL;

    if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm, (void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "jajaja", ">>NATIVE jni failed");
        return -1;
    }
    playerUtils = (*env)->FindClass(env,
            "com/example/customviewcircles/nativeaudio/PlayerUtils");

    if (playerUtils != NULL) {

        globalClass = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, playerUtils);
    }
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

void callMyJavaFunction() {

    JNIEnv* env;
    jmethodID updatePlayerStatus = NULL;
    jobject myObject = NULL;

    if((*mVm)->AttachCurrentThread(mVm, &env, NULL) == JNI_OK) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "jajaja", ">>NATIVE attached successfully");
    }

    if (globalClass != NULL) {

        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "jajaja",
                            ">>NATIVE globalclass not null");

        updatePlayerStatus = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, globalClass,
                "updatePlayerStatus", "()V");

        if (updatePlayerStatus != NULL) {

            myObject = (*env)->NewObject(env, globalClass, updatePlayerStatus);
        }
    }
    (*mVm)->DetachCurrentThread(mVm);

}

 void myCallBackFunction() {
     callMyJavaFunction();
 }
```